# Multiply $3$ or more numbers at the same time.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Consider a set of numbers $N \in \Bbb N $ in the range $[1, M[$, where all the numbers are co-prime with $M$

How can we easily multiply certain numbers of that set at the same time, where computation speed is not a requirement?

> An example for arbitrary numbers would be in a loop to test each $N_i$ if they can
>   be divided by $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 \ldots$ etc (primes) and construct the result by
>   multiplying the primes factors that succeed, Until all $N_i$ reach $1$.

But is there another way without having a primes database?

What I desire is: would be able to compute the product of 4 arbitrary numbers $\in [1,101[$ modulo $101$  ex: $ 4 \times 20  \times 53 \times 100 = 424000 \mod 101 = 2 $

Thank you, regards.

Comment: What do you mean ? Do you want to multiply $k$ numbers in less than $k$ multiplies ? What is the role of $M$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust An algorithm to multiply numbers simultaneously instead of doing (((N1*N2)*N3)*N4), knowing that the set is in a Multiplicative group of integers modulo M

Comment: What is "simultaneously" ??

Comment: I'm glad to see I'm not the only one who doesn't undstand the question.  Why does ((((primefact1*primefact2)*primefact3)....) solve whatever problem ((N1*N2)N3)...) supposedly had?  And what *was* that problem anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $P$ be the  set of  prime factors  of $N$  and call  the function
$g(M).$ Then we have by inclusion-exclusion that

$$g(M) = M! \prod_{S\subseteq P, S\neq \{\}}
h\left(\prod_{p\in S} p,
\bigg\lfloor\frac{M}{\prod_{p\in S} p}\bigg\rfloor\right).$$

where
$$h(m, f)
= \left(f! \times m^f \right)^{\mu(m)}.$$

If you  read Maple consult  the algorithm below.

```
with(numtheory);
with(combinat);

P1 :=
proc(N, M)
option remember;
local q, d;

    q := 1;

    for d to M do
        if gcd(d, N) = 1 then
            q := q*d;
        fi;
    od;

    q;
end;

P2 :=
proc(N, M)
    option remember;
    local d, allp, pset, pm, f, q, r;

    q := M!;

    allp := select(isprime, divisors(N));

    for pset in powerset(allp) minus {{}} do
        pm := mul(p, p in pset);

        f := floor(M/pm);
        r := f! * pm^f;

        q := q*r^mobius(pm);
    od;

    q;
end;
```

**Remark.** Additional simplification yields

$$g(M) = \prod_{S\subseteq P}
h\left(\prod_{p\in S} p,
\bigg\lfloor\frac{M}{\prod_{p\in S} p}\bigg\rfloor\right).$$

**Remark II Apr 10 2016.** Obviously with $M$ large this problem only makes sense if we compute the answer modulo some smaller prime than $M!$ and larger than $M.$ That, however, looks very much like contest math. (The bottleneck here are the expensive factorials, there are better than naive algorithms for this however. Implementing these looks more like a term project. Consult e.g. this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727962/). Factorials can be implemented with prime number sieving as the exponent of a prime in a factorial is simple to compute but sieves are expressly forbidden in this problem and not practical for the $M!$ that one would want to compute.)

Comment: I am not familiar with maple, but I will try to understand it, thank you

Comment: I will do some more editing including formulae shortly.

Comment: The above answers the question for the range being up to $M$ and co-primality with $N.$

Comment: How must I compute a certain table with these two procedure?